# How to create a Processing Language plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, processing

I'm quite a noob programmer and I recently discovered Java Processing Language which can be run on Android.

So far I've been using a dedicated IDE to program it in but I've just found out I can program it in Eclipse which is my preferred IDE. The only problem is that they only tell you which libraries to import when creating a Processing project from a standard Java project. So every time I want to create a new project I have to create a Java project, go through all the import menus, search for the Processing system library, import the files, create a new class and import the library for the class.

Does anyone know how to create an eclipse plugin so I can just go to the NEW directory in eclipse and have a PROCESSING folder and a NEW PROCESSING PROJECT item that already has a generic class with the imported libraries?

I've been looking at online tutorials and I can't even figure out where to start.

The steps to create a Processing project from a Java one are explained [here](http://processing.org/learning/eclipse/).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend having a look at the [Proclipsing plugin](http://code.google.com/p/proclipsing/) which seems to do pretty much what you want to achieve. It's also open source so you can see how it was written and modify if you like.

[image: Proclipsing]

Comment: +1 on the proclipsing plugin. I have used this in the past and it saves time over setting up the project by hand.

Answer (score 1):

A Processing project is a standard Java project with the Processing libraries added to build path. There is nothing more to Processing in this regard. So a specific Eclipse Processing plugin for this seems overkill (there are some other things like the different targets or samples that could make it useful though).

To easen up your current process: Create an Eclipse User Library for the Processing libraries. Menu `Window > Preferences`, `Java > Build Path > User Libraries`, `New...`. Add the Processing libraries. Now you can easily add the whole set to a project (right-click on the newly created Java project in the package explorer, `Build Path > Add libraries > User Library`).

If you want to change the standard template for Java classes to one including everything for Processing: `Window > Preferences, Java > Code Style > Code Templates, Code > New Java files`. This changes *every* newly created class, maybe it is better to just create a simple template to manually call at start: `Java > Editor > Templates, New...`. Then you would call the template every time you create a Processing main class but not for "normal" classes.

Ok... regarding the target audience of Processing a plugin may be a good idea. But then there is the dedicated Processing UI. Eclipse is not exactly a good introductory IDE.